# Split quoted of a string java

Tags: java, regex

I would like some help with the following question.

I have the following string

```
1,1,0,3, '2014-12-02 12:15:13', '2015-05-20', 'string', 'other string', 1,2,1, NULL, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL
```

and would make the split and put in an array only those quoted ignoring others. You could even separate by commas, but the sequences vary.

I am using the following regex:

```
 String splitStr[] = str.split("\'([^\\']*)\'");
```

but the output is as follows:

```
1,1,0,3,, ,,,, ,,, 1,2,1, NULL,, ,,, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

What I need is exactly the opposite, something like this:

```
'2014-12-02 12:15:13', '2015-05-20', 'string', 'other string','', ''
```

Comment: Instead of `split` do a `match` using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes

Comment: Sorry, but I'm Going back to the developing java after many years, could explain me better? Thank you! @anubhava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Java:

```
String str = str = "1,1,0,3, '2014-12-02 12:15:13', '2015-05-\\'20', 'string', 'other string', 1,2,1, NULL, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'([^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*)'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("val: [" + m.group(1) + ']');
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ7gK9/2)

**Output:**

```
val: [2014-12-02 12:15:13]
val: [2015-05-\'20]
val: [string]
val: [other string]
val: []
val: []
```

Comment: simpler pattern suggestion: `Pattern.compile("('.*?')");`

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! I stay use my regex, but still works!

Comment: @Assaf: This regex ignores escaped characters and captures `'2015-05-\\'20'` in one group

Comment: it does ignore escaped characters, but it doesn't capture the above in one group.

Comment: Of course it captures that in group #1, check the shown output in answer and also the demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Regex doesn't support state, so it's basically impossible to do this as a general case. You can't "count" how many quote marks you've seen in regex.

You can find libraries to do things like this or loop through the String and split it either matching it yourself or using a pattern matcher.

Comment: there's another way to do something like this?

Comment: @UbirajaraRodrigues See anubhava's answer. That's one way to do the loop :)